# User control in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I’m beginner for ASP.NET MVC , so I need to functioning create and edit using one user control (may use 2 views)

How can I do this.

Ex : Create new Product details and Edit product details

Thz....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use **[Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450.aspx)**. The followings are the great blog post series by Brad Wilson:

1. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html
2. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html
3. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html
4. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html
5. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-5-master-page-templates.html

Good luck!